# Calculations on the values of columns which numbers are given by variables in Gnuplot

Tags: variables, gnuplot

I'm using loop for plotting, number of the column is determined by the variable. When I want to calculate the difference between two columns values this doesn't work. 
What I want to do looks approximately in this way:

```
plot for [i=2:n-1] fn u 1:($i-$1) w lp
```

Is it not possible in principle to use the variable column number for calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `column(i)`: `$1` is a shortcut for `column(1)`.

```
plot for [i=2:n-1] fn u 1:(column(i)-$1) w lp
```

Comment: This absolutely a life saver. Quick question: how to plot only values equals or below a specific y threshold for all columns? E.g. `u 1:(column(i)=<5)) `?